# Backbone.js View not rendering EL

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am having a problem the Backbone.js View not rendering. My code is fairly simple and looks like this:

```
TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function() {
        var template = _.template($("#table_template").html(), {});
        alert(this.el);
        this.el.html('Go');
        //this.el.html(template);
    },
    events: {

    },
});
```

And this is the code for instaniting the object and setting the el

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var t  = $("#table_1");
                //This works!!!
                t.html('Test');

                //Passing the element as the el, never works
                var table = new TableView({el : t});
            });
        </script>
```

Except it always says in the console: 
U`ncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html' .`
Am I doing something wrong here? I'm using Jquery.1.7.2, backbone 0.9.2, underscore 1.3.3 and json2.

Comment: Yes it should so I can mark it as correct. I wish the tutorials they gave for this were correct also :P

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial which says you can do this?

Comment: This one right here: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/  ...unless I read this wrong

Comment: Yeah that's a mistake, the author even says a few paragraphs above that `el` is a element and not a jQuery object but then uses it as a jQuery object with `this.el.html( template );` The comments to the article say this as well but he hasn't updated it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.el` is an element not a jQuery object. Try `$(this.el).html()` or `this.$el.html()`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var table = new TableView({el : "#table_1"});
```